# how to simply read barcode with kivy from camera and send the result to a method to process the barcode?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I would like to have a button on the screen that would open the camera and read a barcode and I would like to show the image of the product based on the barcode and if I press the button again It opens the camera again and does the same job.

Before asking here, I searched examples but couldn't make it working with my limited understanding of kivy.

I have tried using:
https://github.com/kivy-garden/zbarcam
It has following issues for my usecase.

1. Camera is always open, would like to open only at button click
2. Doesn't show the output of barcode not sure if it is reading or not.
3. doesn't say what is the way to pass the output to a method so it can
   be processed further

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately zbarcam of kivy-garden is designed in such away it will always keep the camera running in the background which heats up the device and consumes a lot of power.

Here is an implementation of zbarcam and qrcode that I have created earlier(username:admin ,password:admin). The actual implementation requests the username and password from Mysql database, let me know if you need that.

calc method can be used to get the qrcode string and display the image of the product.

**Update**

My implementation uses KivyMD here [https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD](http://%20https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD) so you need to have it installed by using

```
pip install kivymd==0.104.1
```

It has QR generator from kivygarden here https://pypi.org/project/kivy-garden.qrcode/ you also need to have it installed.

```
pip install kivy-garden.qrcode
```

And of course you need pyzbar installed as it is a dependency for both packages

```
pip install pyzbar
```

[image]

demo.kv

```
#:import ZBarCam kivy_garden.zbarcam.ZBarCam
#:import ZBarSymbol pyzbar.pyzbar.ZBarSymbol
#:import QRCodeWidget kivy_garden.qrcode

MyLayout:
    scr_mngr: scr_mngr
    orientation: 'vertical'
    ScreenManager:
        id: scr_mngr
        Screen:
            id: screen1
            name: 'screen1'
            MDSpinner:
                id:spinner
                size_hint: None, None
                size: dp(46), dp(46)
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
                active: False
            MDToolbar:
                md_bg_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
                title: "Login Screen"
                pos_hint:{"top": 1}
                elevation: 11
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                padding: "16dp"
                spacing: "16dp"
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                pos_hint: {"center_y": .6}
                
                MDLabel:
                    text: "Log In"
                    halign: "center"
                    font_style: "H4"
                    size_hint_y: None
                MDTextField:
                    id: username
                    hint_text: "Username "
                    helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
                    required: True
                
                MDTextField:
                    id: password
                    hint_text: "Password "
                    helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
                    required: True
                    password: True


            MDRaisedButton:
                text: "LOGIN"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.3}

                on_release: root.check_data_login()
        Screen:
            id: screen2
            name: 'screen2'
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                MDToolbar:
                    md_bg_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
                    id: toolbar
                    title: "Page 2"
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    MDTabs:
                        Tab:
                            text: "Scan"        
                            ZBarCam:
                                id: zbarcam
                                # optional, by default checks all types
                                code_types: ZBarSymbol.QRCODE, ZBarSymbol.EAN13
                                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.75}
                                size_hint: [1, 1]
                            MDLabel:
                                id: qrlabel
                                #size_hint: None, None
                                size: self.texture_size[0], 50
                                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.3}
                                halign: "center"
                                text: ', '.join([str(symbol.data) for symbol in zbarcam.symbols])
                                on_text: root.calc(self.text)
                                opacity: 1
                        Tab:
                            text: "Generate"
                            BoxLayout:
                                orientation: 'vertical'
                                padding: "16dp"
                                spacing: "16dp"
                                MDTextField:
                                    id: txtfld
                                    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.75}
                                    size_hint: [0.8,0.2]
                                    hint_text: "Text to be encoded"
                                    mode: "rectangle"
                                    on_text: qr.data = txtfld.text
                                QRCodeWidget:
                                    id: qr
                                    data: ''
                                    size_hint: [0.8,0.3]
                                    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.3}
                                    show_border: False
```

login.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager as scr_mngr
from kivymd.toast import toast
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
        
class Tab(FloatLayout, MDTabsBase):
    pass

class MyLayout(BoxLayout):
        
    def check_data_login(self):
                
        self.ids['spinner'].active=True
        username = self.ids['username'].text
        password = self.ids['password'].text
        print(username)
        print(password)
        if  not username and not password:
            toast("Username and password are required")
        elif  not username:
            toast("Username is required ")
        elif not password:
            toast("Password is required")
        else:
            if username == "admin" and  password == "admin":
                self.ids['spinner'].active=False
                self.change_screen("screen2")
            else:
                self.ids['spinner'].active=False
                toast("Wrong username or password")
        
    def change_screen(self, screen, *args):
        self.scr_mngr.current = screen
        
    def calc(self, instance):
        print(self.ids['qrlabel'].text)
        
class DemoApp(MDApp):
        pass
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Window.show_cursor = True
    Window.size = (360, 680)
    DemoApp().run()
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. Isn't there an easy way to open the camera only at a button click and turn off as soon as the reading is done? This way seems very impractical.
what is that implementation you shared credentials? maybe you wanted to share a link as well?

Comment: I tried the code above, it doesn't raise any issue in logs but the window closes immediately after opening. Program terminates itself.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the required dependencies and removed some unnecessarily imported packages. Try the new code username is "admin" and password is "admin"

Comment: Doesn't work. Any tips on doing it without the imports in the .kv file?

Comment: Greetings, where the kv file are read or imported in the py executable?

Comment: MyLayout.check_data_login couldn't be a boolean functinon(def)?

Comment: Thank you for sharing this code! Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I recently started with kivy and struggled a lot with the ZBarCam as well.
I  posted a question and thanks to the comments and answers I could finally come to a working code that:

- Starts with camera off
- When clicking a button starts the ZbarCam and starts reading
- When something is detected (i.e QR is read), ZBarCam stops (as well as the camera) and saves the text in a variable which then you can process it as you want

You can find the working example in https://stackoverflow.com/a/73077097/6018801

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I recently created a android qr code scanner app with ZBarCam.
You can control the camera via the xcamera like this with ids.
self.ids.<zbarcam_ids>.xcamera.play = True

I set it to false when the app is build and use screen manager to with on_enter/leave to enable/disble the camera.

Comment: Do you have an example of how do you call `self.ids.<zbarcam_ids>.xcamera.play = False`   when the app is built?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same think, my way hope it helps:

`try:
         import kivy
         from kivy.app import App
         from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
         from kivy.uix.image import Image
         from kivy.uix.button import Button
         from kivy.uix.label import Label
         from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
         from kivy_garden.zbarcam import ZBarCam
     except:
         import subprocess
         subprocess.check_call(["python", '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'kivy'])
         subprocess.check_call(["python", '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'kivy_garden'])
         subprocess.check_call(["python", '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'pyzbar'])
class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        self.box = BoxLayout()
        self.box.orientation = 'vertical'
        self.box.spacing = 20
        self.box.padding = 20
        self.logo = Image(source='logo.png')
        self.box.add_widget(self.logo)
        self.btn_add_pick = Button(font_size=30, text='Add Pick')
        self.box.add_widget(self.btn_add_qr)
        self.btn_remove_pick = Button(font_size=30, text='Delet Pick')
        self.box.add_widget(self.btn_remove_pick)
        self.add_widget(self.box)

class CameraScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        self.box = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical')
        self.cam = ZBarCam()
        self.cam.play = False 
        self.btn_close = Button(font_size=30, size_hint_y=None, text='Get')
        self.box.add_widget(self.cam)
        self.box.add_widget(self.btn_close)
        self.add_widget(self.box)

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kv):
        super().__init__(**kv)
        ms = MainScreen(name="main")
        ms.btn_add_pick.bind(on_press=self.switch_to_camera)
        ms.btn_remove_pick.bind(on_press=self.switch_to_camera)
        self.add_widget(ms)
        cs = CameraScreen(name = "camera")
        cs.btn_close.bind(on_press=self.switch_to_main)
        self.add_widget(cs)

    def switch_to_camera(self, instance):
        self.current='camera'
        self.transition.direction='down'
    

    def switch_to_main(self, instance):
        self.current = 'main'
        self.transition.direction='up'

class WoodWQApp(App):
    def build(self):
        wm = WindowManager()
        wm.current = 'main'
        return wm

if __name__=="__main__":
   WoodWQApp().run()`