# kivy load camera (zbarscan) on click button

Tags: python, kivy, zbar

I've just started my first kivy app. The app is intended to start with button "Start Scan" and then show up the QR scanner built with ZBarCam.

I'm using Screens with the `ScreenManager` to change from the button view to the camera view (with zbarcam), the problem is that I realized that the camera is initialized from the beginning , so before clicking on the button the camera is already on (I know it because the led from the camera is on).

I don't know if Screen should not be used in this case, or if is there a way to tell the app to do not initialize all screens.

The code I'm using is the following:

QrApp.py:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class QrReader(Screen):
    pass

class ScanButton(Screen):
    pass

class QrApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    QrApp().run()
```

qrapp.kv:

```
ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager
    ScanButton:
        id: scan_btn
        name: 'scan_btn'
        manager: 'screen_manager'
    QrReader:
        id: qr_reader
        name: 'qr_reader'
        manager: 'screen_manager'


<ScanButton>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text:'Start Scan'
            font_size:"50sp"
            color: [0, 255, 255, .67]
            on_press: app.root.current = 'qr_reader'

<QrReader>:
    #:import ZBarCam kivy_garden.zbarcam.ZBarCam
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        ZBarCam:
            id:qrcodecam
        Label:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.texture_size[0], 50
            text: ' '.join([str(symbol.data) for symbol in qrcodecam.symbols])
```

Thanks!

==== ALTERNATIVE BASED IN A COMMENT (still fails) ====

Based on the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73067952/kivy-load-camera-zbarscan-on-click-button?noredirect=1#comment129053076_73067952) from [n4321d](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13592469/n4321d) I tried to add the ZBarCam as widget in the `QrReader` Screen. While I can now initiate the camera when the widget is added, I don't see how I can get the `symbols` that is, the text read from the QR.

This alternative code is the following:

QrApp.py:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class QrReader(Screen):
    def on_enter(self):
        from kivy_garden.zbarcam import ZBarCam
        zbarcam = ZBarCam()
        self.add_widget(zbarcam)
        self.add_widget(Label(
            text='PRINT SYMBOLS', #' '.join([str(symbol.data) for symbol in zbarcam.symbols] does not work
            size_hint=(None,None),
            size=(Window.width*0.1, Window.height*0.1),
            center=(Window.width*0.3, Window.height*0.5)))

class ScanButton(Screen):
    pass

class QrApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    QrApp().run()
```

qrapp.kv

```
ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager
    ScanButton:
        id: scan_btn
        name: 'scan_btn'
        manager: 'screen_manager'
    QrReader:
        id: qr_reader
        name: 'qr_reader'
        manager: 'screen_manager'

<ScanButton>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text:'Start Scan'
            font_size:"50sp"
            color: [0, 255, 255, .67]
            on_press:
                app.root.current = 'qr_reader'


<QrReader>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
```

====== SOLUTION ========

My workaround solution is posted as an answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73077097/6018801)

Comment: it may need to create ZBarCam using code (when you press button) instead of using `kv`. OR you should check if there is some function or settings to stop it at start.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to create ZBarCam using code, when pressing button? Because the examples only use kv

Comment: you can use the on_enter method of the QrReader screen to add the ZBarCam widget to your QR Reader screen, and on_exit to remove it, assuming that the ZBarCam widget initiates the camera

Comment: Hi @n4321d  thanks for the idea. I now can open the camera only when needed but now I cannot read the info from the QR code.. I have updated the entry with this alternative idea. Do you maybe see how can I  get the text from the QR code now with this version?

Answer (score 2):

First:
I would also add an on_leave function where you remove your cam widget otherwise you will keep adding new widgets every time you load it.

I dont have a working cam now , so i cannot test your code. Looking at your code I think you have to bind the text in your Label to the text in zbarcam.symbols with a function: self.label = Label(....); zbarcam.bind(symbols=lambda *x: setattr(self.label, "text", str(x[1]))) or somethign like that.

Here is an example using a random text generator instead of ZBarCam (since i cannot run that).

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
import random
from kivy.clock import Clock


kv_str = """
ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager
    ScanButton:
        id: scan_btn
        name: 'scan_btn'
        manager: 'screen_manager'
    QrReader:
        id: qr_reader
        name: 'qr_reader'
        manager: 'screen_manager'

<ScanButton>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text:'Start Scan'
            font_size:"50sp"
            color: [0, 255, 255, .67]
            on_press:
                app.root.current = 'qr_reader'


<QrReader>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
"""

class ZBarCam(Label):
    symbols = ListProperty([])
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.gen_rand_text, 1)

    def gen_rand_text(self, *args):
        self.text = random.choice(['aaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'ccccc'])
        self.symbols.append(self.text)
        if len(self.symbols) > 3:
            del self.symbols[0]


class QrReader(Screen):
    def on_enter(self):
        self.zbarcam = ZBarCam()
        self.add_widget(self.zbarcam)
        self.label = Label(
            text='PRINT SYMBOLS', #' '.join([str(symbol.data) for symbol in zbarcam.symbols] does not work
            size_hint=(None,None),
            size=(Window.width*0.1, Window.height*0.1),
            center=(Window.width*0.3, Window.height*0.5))
        self.add_widget(self.label)
        self.zbarcam.bind(symbols = lambda *x: setattr(self.label, "text", str(x[1])))
    
    def on_leave(self, *args):
        self.remove_widget(self.zbarcam)
        self.remove_widget(self.label)

class ScanButton(Screen):
    pass

class QrApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv_str)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    QrApp().run()
```

if it still does not work you might have to call self.zbarcam.start() too in the on_enter method after adding it

hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73073497/6018801) from [n4321d](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13592469/n4321d) I finally found a solution.

I also struggled releasing the camera, as `zbarcam.stop()` stops zbarcam but camera was apparently still open (led was on). After digging a lot, I found this [workaround](https://github.com/kivy-garden/xcamera/blob/2e210c8875cabe3e405a8233b5e57917e712d562/tests/test_main.py#L11)  which seems to work well to release the camera.

I also merged the button and qr reader in the same Class and I no longer use `kv` file, in this example. The final code is the following:

QrApp.py:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy_garden.zbarcam import ZBarCam

class QrScanner(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(QrScanner, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        btn1 = Button(text='Scan Me',  font_size="50sp")
        btn1.bind(on_press=self.callback)
        self.add_widget(btn1)

    def callback(self, instance):
        """On click button, initiate zbarcam and schedule text reader"""
        self.remove_widget(instance) # remove button
        self.zbarcam = ZBarCam()
        self.add_widget(self.zbarcam)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.read_qr_text, 1)

    def read_qr_text(self, *args):
        """Check if zbarcam.symbols is filled and stop scanning in such case"""
        if(len(self.zbarcam.symbols) > 0): # when something is detected
            self.qr_text = self.zbarcam.symbols[0].data # text from QR
            Clock.unschedule(self.read_qr_text, 1)
            self.zbarcam.stop() # stop zbarcam
            self.zbarcam.ids['xcamera']._camera._device.release() # release camera



class QrApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return QrScanner()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    QrApp().run()
```

Comment: Your code works in that it does indeed release the camera but doing so appears to break zbarcam in that If I back out to another screen and go back to camera again then code blows up with "site-packages\kivy_garden\xcamera\xcamera.kv is loaded multiples times, you might have unwanted behaviors". I have tried to destroy everything I could but have been unable to restart the camera.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to lazy-load kivy `Screen`s. Try this as a workaround: Do not let `ScreenManager` know about all `Screen`s. Use `switch_to` to remove the current screen and load the desired one instead. Check [Kivy docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager.switch_to) to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe so?

```
from kivy_garden.zbarcam import ZBarCam
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField

class MenuScreen(MDScreen):
    zbarcam: ZBarCam = ObjectProperty()
    qrfield: MDTextField = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.__cam_release()

    def scan(self, instance):
        self.__cam_release()

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.zbarcam.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.__cam_open()
        return super().on_touch_down(touch)

    def __cam_release(self):
        if self.zbarcam.xcamera._camera._device.isOpened():
            self.zbarcam.stop()
            self.zbarcam.xcamera._camera._device.release()

    def __cam_open(self):
        if not self.zbarcam.xcamera._camera._device.isOpened():
            self.zbarcam.xcamera._camera._device.open(0)
            self.zbarcam.start()
```

Comment: Users find it difficult to understand code only answers with no explanation. Please consider adding some description explaining how it solves the problem or add comments in the source code at appropriate places.